# My console won't end the program unless if I input a comma. Why?

Tags: c++, console

I'm trying to build a program that asks the user to input numbers into a vector and that displays those numbers towards the console. Everytime I input the numbers the program won't stop running unless if I put a comma. How do I fix this?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int series_of_numbers;
    vector<int> seriesVector;

    cout << "Enter a series of numbers ending with 0, separated by space." << endl;

    while (cin >> series_of_numbers) {
        seriesVector.push_back(series_of_numbers);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < seriesVector.size(); ++i) {
        cout << seriesVector[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

My console
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RikgT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your program will keep reading values until either a stream error, or your vector throws `std::bad_alloc` and the process terminates.

When you put a comma in the input, that can result in a stream error because you're trying to do formatted input into a `int` value which never contains a comma.

The problem is that the program does not know how many values you intended to input, and so it will happily keep waiting for more if possible. In many terminals, you can end the input by pressing Ctrl-D (sometimes followed by Enter).

Your actual prompt is:

> Enter a series of numbers ending with 0, separated by space.

Your loop is not enforcing *either* of these constraints. Right now, it'll allow any amount of whitespace (including newlines) and it does not check for the sentinel value of 0 to end the input.

So you can choose how to approach it. This will read values until the stream errors or a zero is read:

```
int val;
while (cin >> val && val != 0) {
    seriesVector.push_back(val);
}
```

Alternatively, you can read a single line of input, and then read whitespace-separated `int` values from that. This approach does not require the special zero value to denote the end. You can simply parse all values from the line:

```
string line;
if (getline(cin, line)) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    int val;
    while (iss >> val) {
        seriesVector.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

Note that I changed your variable name for a single value. The name `series_of_numbers` implies more than one number, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think you mean ``iss >> val`` , not ``line >> val`` ?

Comment: Whoops yeah, will fix that thanks :)